# Start django on production with python version 3.7

Tags: django, python-3.x

On production, I am using *Django 2.1 + Nginx + uWSGI*. Now, I am planning to migrate to *Django 3*. Django 3 requires python version 3.6+, but my current python version is 3.5.
I have installed python 3.7 on my **dev** server from source as `make altinstall` so on dev server I can run it as `python37 manage.py runserver`, but on production server how can I define python version to 3.7 to start server?
Here is my uwsgi.ini

```
#mysite_uwsgi.ini
[uwsgi]    
chdir           = /var/www/dostavka    
module          = dostavka.wsgi       
master          = true    
processes       = 10    
socket          = /var/www/dostavka/dostavka.sock    
chmod-socket    = 666    
vacuum          = true
```

Then i run it using command

```
uwsgi --ini /var/www/dostavka/mysite_uwsgi.ini --daemonize /var/www/uwsgi.log --uid www-data --gid www-data
```

I am not using virtualenv at production.

Comment: What's preventing you from doing the same on production? How are you starting your server on production?

Comment: Instead of installing multiple python versions you can use pyenv (https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

Comment: Consider http://serverfault.com as alternative to ask…

Comment: Any error you got?

Comment: @Debendra i didn't start operation yet, i can't start operation before some points is not clear

Comment: are you using emperor mode?

Comment: @Debendra no, it is only one project under uwsgi proccess

Comment: The, how you are specifying the uwsgi executable? I guess you are using uwsgi as emerior mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have solved the problem. After `make altnstall` python 3.7 on production server, I have re-installed *uWSGI* and *Django* by using `pip3.7 install uwsgi` and `pip3.7 intall django`. After that *uWSGI* start to use new python version 3.7.
Also, if you have any other applications connected to *django*, you need to install them using `pip3.7 intall xxxx`.